# Custom theme interferes with snackbar background color

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport, android-snackbar

Trying out the new Design Support Library, I added a snackbar; but unlike its main background, the text area is not colored with the default value of `#323232`. Instead, it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Sud.jpg). It seems to take its color from the `android:background` value defined in the custom theme in my `styles.xml`, which goes like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:background">#4f4f5e</item>
    ...
</style>
```

If I try to forcefully color it with

```
View snackbarView = snackbar.getView(); 
snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
```

it only impacts the main background, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Iew6.jpg), and the text background still gets colored by the custom theme. Is there a way to both keep my custom theme, and have a standard snackbar? Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

To change the Snackbar's background colour you can do the following from code:

```
Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(...);
ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) snack.getView();
group.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.red));
snack.show();
```

Instead of red you can use the Snackbar's default colour: #323232

Comment: getColor() is deprecated.

Comment: If you using support4 library then you can use ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorRed);

Answer (score 7):

`.setBackgroundColor` allows you to change background color of snackbar

```
msnackBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#009688"));
```

or

```
 msnackBar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.BLUE)););
```

[Here](http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/08/android-snackbar-design-support-library.html) is complete tutorial to use snackbar using design support library.

Answer (score 7):

The snackbar contains a TextView, so you need to change the background color for both, the snackbar the way you already did,  and then the TextView like this:

```
View snackbarView = snackbar.getView(); 
TextView textView = (TextView)snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text); 
textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
```

Comment: ^This! The only correct answer, every other above just doesn't understand what causes conflict and doesn't explicitly say to change text background! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This effect happens when in style attribute `android:background` is set.

Removing that will of course affect all layouts in your application but snackbar will be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete sample:

```
Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null);
                ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) snack.getView();
                group.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.blue));
                snack.show();
```

replace **MainActivity.this** with your currently activity or getAppContext()

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create your own Snackbar class and simulate Snackbar's make method. Doing this, you just have to use this class instead of android's snackbar widget.

**Snackbar.class**

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.annotation.IntDef;
import android.support.annotation.IntRange;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.view.View;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

public class Snackbar {

    /** Snackbar's lengths **/
    public static final int LENGTH_SHORT = android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT;
    public static final int LENGTH_LONG = android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG;
    public static final int LENGTH_INDEFINITE = android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE;

    @NonNull
    public static android.support.design.widget.Snackbar make(@NonNull View view, @NonNull CharSequence text,
                                                              @Duration int duration) {
        android.support.design.widget.Snackbar snackbar = android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(view, text, duration);
        // TODO: This is where you have to customize your snackbar
        snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        return snackbar;
    }

    @NonNull
    public static android.support.design.widget.Snackbar make(@NonNull View view, @StringRes int resId, @Duration int duration) {
        return make(view, view.getResources().getText(resId), duration);
    }

    // Optional
    @IntDef({LENGTH_INDEFINITE, LENGTH_SHORT, LENGTH_LONG})
    @IntRange(from = 1)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface Duration {}

}
```

**Use:**

```
// WARNING: Make sure you're using your snackbar's package
import com.mypackage.custom_views.Snackbar;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        Snackbar.make(view, R.string.my_msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library: https://github.com/SandroMachado/restaurant

```
new Restaurant(MainActivity.this, "Snackbar with custom background and text color", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    .setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)
    .show();
```

Disclaimer: I made the library.

Answer (score 1):

**this is how i'm using custom snackbar**

```
  Snackbar snackbar_network = Snackbar.make(rLayout, "Your Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .setAction("EXIT", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(final View v) {


                                  finish();

                            }
                        });
```

> **Action Text Color**

```
 snackbar_network.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);
```

**Action Message Text Color**

```
  final View sbView = snackbar_network.getView();
                final TextView tv = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
```

**Set Snackbar Background**

```
sbView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MapsActivity.this, R.color.black));

        snackbar_network.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Works this way for me:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(lineatLayout, "TEXT", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) snackbar.getView();
        group.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.yourColor));
        TextView textView = (TextView) group.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.yor collor));

        snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue & unfortunately no solution works for me Hence I write my own solution where I set background color for parent view too.

```
    TextView snackbarTextView = snackbar.getView().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    snackbarTextView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorPrimary));

    ViewParent parentView = snackbarTextView.getParent();
    if (parentView instanceof View) {
        ((View) parentView).setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorPrimary));
    }

    View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
    snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorPrimary));

    snackbar.show();
```